# Sending a vector3 to script from patches is not working

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio, cannon.js

So I'm making a ball bounce in spark AR with cannon.js. Everything was working fine until I wanted to get the position of the forehead from the facetracker via the patch editor to a script.

Error:

```
    Error:Exception in HostFunction: valueOf() called on a Signal. This probably means that you are
    trying to perform an arithmetic operation on a signal like +, -, *, etc. Use functions .add, .sub(), 
    etc on the signal instead or .subscribeWithSnapshot() on an EventSource to get the signal's current value on a callback.
at ScalarSignal::valueOf (native)
{
"line": 4841,
"column": 19,
"sourceURL": "cannon.js"
}
```

[My patches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfxD7.png) that send the vector3 of the forehead to the script.

this piece of code is giving the error:

```
var pos = Patches.getVectorValue('HeadPos');
groundBody.position.set(pos);
```

I sadly can't find anything online about sending a vector3 from the patches to a 'Working' value in the script, Does somebody know how to send a vector3 value ta a script and the use it as a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a selution when working with cannon.js. cannon.js has a kind of update function so you can use .pinLastValue() because it does this every frame in order to update the physics.

My code:

```
// Create time interval loop for cannon 
Time.setInterval(function (time) {
    if (lastTime !== undefined) {
        let dt = (time - lastTime) / 1000;
        world.step(fixedTimeStep, dt, maxSubSteps)

     // Get the head position values from the patches
     var headVal1 = Patches.getScalarValue("HeadPosX").pinLastValue();
     var headVal2 = Patches.getScalarValue("HeadPosY").pinLastValue();
     var headVal3 = Patches.getScalarValue("HeadPosZ").pinLastValue();

     // Set the position of the head hitbox to the headposition in the physics world
     HeadBody.position.x = headVal1;
     HeadBody.position.y = headVal2;
     HeadBody.position.z = headVal3;
   }

    lastTime = time
}, timeInterval);
```

This code gets the x, y and z values individually from the patches where I send these values individually as well. I could have done it as a Vector3 from both sides as well, but I thought this looked nicer and made it easier to edit the values individually through the patches instead of packing it as a Vector3 again.